# Good practice to programming in Java, override and hierarchy

Tags: java

I've a question about good practice to programming java.

The problem is:

I doing override a method declared in Class B. This method that override will be in Class C. The hierarchy is Class C extends B that extends A.
The method is present in each class like this:

```
class A{
    ...
    public void overrideMe(){ ... }
}
class B extends A{
    public void overrideMe(){
     ...
     ...
     super.overrideMe()
    }
}
```

These classes is common for each project and the projects are many for these reason I can't modify this class unless exceptional cases.

I have to override the method overrideMe() to add code inside but at the end of the method I still need call method of class A.

Now the question are Two, is better:

1) Create a method in Class B that call only method overrideMe() in class A and extends overrideMe():

```
class B extends A{
 public void callOverrideMeOfSuperClass(){ super.overrideMe(); }
 public void overrideMe(){
     ...
     ...
     super.overrideMe()
    }
 }
class C extends B{
 public void overrideMe(){
     ...
     super.callOverrideMeOfSuperClass()
 }
}
```

2) Create a custom method in class B, this method will be included in overrideMe() of class B and extends only for my project in class C:

```
class B extends A{
 public void customCode(){ (not code inside) }
 public void overrideMe(){
     ...
     customeCode();
     ...
     super.overrideMe()
    }
 }
class C extends B{
 public void customeCode(){
     do something;
 }
}
```

FYI: These class, A and B, are more method and code.

Ok so, issue that we will have to give in order to importance:

1) Good programming practice of java
2) Less impact on code
3) Less impact for all project. These project are different project but share a common base code.
4) If i change common code each project are to check this code to are sure that there isn't impact for project.

Is better the first solution or the second and why?

Thank's all!!

RainJoker

Answer (score 1):

Usually code that expects extensions by derived classes implement methods in the second form you presented.
Such methods are very often named like `doOriginalMethodName`, so `doOverrideMe` in your case.
This ensures execution of the original code plus the behavior of the derived one.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class A {

  public void extendMe() {
    // modify internal state
    ... 

    // allow extension
    doExtendMe();
  }

  protected void doExtendMe() {
  } 
}

public class B extends A {

  @Override
  protected void doExtendMe() {
    // modify state of B
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is better create a method that do nothing and include them in a method overrideMe() that create a method to call overrideMe() inside of "mother class" A? The second solution create a method that only one project implements and use. In the first solution we create a method that each project can use. U have to think that we are in a context with more project and the code can be reused or not. The code that u can reuse is in Class A and B, C in create in a single project.

Comment: I've added some sample, please the the my answer above.

Comment: You haven't understand my question. In a context that you can NEVER delete code in class A and B but if anything you can only add, ever in exceptional cases for example in this case, what do you chose? Add method that call super super class bypass middle class B or add method inside method override() to insert my custom code?

Comment: We take account also: 1) Good programming practice of java 2) Less impact on code 3) Less impact for all project. These project are different project but share a common base code. 4) If i change common code each project are to check this code to are sure that there isn't impact for project.